# What is the usage of HttpContext.Items dictionary object?

Tags: asp.net

When and how do I use the Httpcontext.items dictionary object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a dictionary you can use to get/set data in the Request context. 
There you can set values to share across events in the same Request.

Answer (score 2):

It is used as cache to share item between handlers and controls during **one** web request. [Here's more info](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx).

Comment: That article has confused me even more. Any other article that you are aware of?

Comment: Don't bother with the above link, its dead and redirects to a gambling page in 2022.  I should really check dates on these SO posts..